# Is there a version of EasyMiner for Mac?

Tags: mining-software, butterfly-labs

I'm thinking about possibly getting a BitForce Jalapeno (http://products.butterflylabs.com/4-5gh-bitcoin-miner.html) It says that it needs "EasyMiner" which is only for Windows. (The download page links to a .exe file). Does anyone know if they're planning to make a version for mac? Are they any alternatives? (In software, not hardware)

Comment: Does the Mac version support ASIC already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know whether EasyMiner will be ported to Mac. But there will be several other miners supporting the BitForce Jalapeno and other BFL ASIC products.

If you want a user-friendly alternative you may want to try out BitMinter client. It has been thoroughly tested with BFL FPGAs mining on Macs. Support for BFL ASICs will be added as soon as possible. This miner is available from http://bitminter.com. I am the author of this miner.

Comment: Where can I download that?

Comment: URL added above.

Comment: Where on that site can I download it?

Comment: Just press "engine start" on the website. It's distributed through Java Webstart. Alternatively you can start it from the command line aswell: javaws http://bitminter.com/client/bitminter.jnlp

Answer (score 0):

EasyMiner should run fine in a virtual machine, but you can alternatively grab MacMiner which unlike bitminter doesn't require java

[MacMiner website](http://macminer.fabulouspanda.com/)